# Somar dados em cascata de uma coluna no Access

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Olá!

Preciso realizar uma consulta que me devolve o saldo semanal de determinados produtos no estoque. Por exemplo:

```
Ano/Semana | Saíram | Entraram | Saldo
______________________________________
2015/01    | 4      | 10       | [Entraram] - [Saíram]
2015/02    | 7      | 2        | ([Entraram] - [Saíram]) + Saldo da linha acima
```

E assim até acabaram os registros. Sempre pegando o resultado da subtração dos produtos que entraram com os produtos que saíram e somando com o saldo do registro imediatamente acima.

Não tenho ideia de por onde começar...

Comment: Cara, eu tentei formatar a sua tabela. Como estava meio confusa eu não sei se está certo, se estiver errado me avise que eu desfaço a edição *=)*

Comment: É isso aí! Valeu, é minha primeira pergunta ao site...

Comment: É eu vi que é sua primeira pergunta. Tranquilo, com o tempo você pega o jeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!

Considerando que a estrutura da tabela que contém os dados seja algo parecido com:

```
Data        AnoSemana  Sairam  Entraram
01/01/2016  2016/01     5       10
01/02/2016  2016/06     3       8
01/03/2016  2016/10    9       6
01/04/2016  2016/14    3       5
```

Obs.: caso não tenha a coluna **AnoSemana**, você pode usar a seguinte função: `Format([data];"yyyy") & "/" & Format(PartData("ww";[data]);"00")`.

Segue a consulta SQL para gerar o extrato por semana:

```
SELECT 
    ESTOQUE.AnoSemana
    , ESTOQUE.ENTRARAM
    , ESTOQUE.SAIRAM
    , (SELECT Sum(Nz(ENTRARAM)-Nz(SAIRAM))
       FROM ESTOQUE AS TB
       WHERE TB.AnoSemana<=ESTOQUE.AnoSemana) AS SALDO
FROM ESTOQUE
ORDER BY ESTOQUE.Data;
```

Resultado da consulta:

```
AnoSemana   ENTRARAM    SAIRAM  SALDO
2016/1      10          5       5
2016/6      8           3       10
2016/10     6           9       7
2016/14     5           3       9
```