# Somar dados em cascata de uma coluna no Access com Status por Linha

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Preciso criar um controle de compras por linha onde gera uma necessidade de compra considerando a quantidade de cada produto por cliente frente a disponibilidade do estoque.

Como no exemplo da tabela abaixo tenho um item XXX que se repete em diferentes clientes com quantidades diferentes o meu estoque é de 10un e a demanda total é de 21un para a primeira linha eu tenho disponibilidade não sendo necessário compra porem para a segunda linha preciso comprar 01un, **STK-demanda do cliente A**, na terceira linha preciso de 10un, **STK-demanda do cliente A-demanda do cliente B**.

É possível criar este tipo de controle?

Observação trabalho em uma empresa que tem cadastrado 15mil produtos onde recebemos pedidos todos os dias.

Exemplo tabela Anexo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado tabela Anexo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando adaptar este cód. que achei neste site do Sr AleGR no topico [Somar dados em cascata de uma coluna no Access](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102030/somar-dados-em-cascata-de-uma-coluna-no-access), mas como ele soma por data e o BD onde estou trabalhando o mesmo item se repete em ao menos 15 clientes no mesmo dia não estou conseguindo.